# Oracle Scheduler Job - Exporting of CSV File every 16:01

Tags: oracle, database-design, jobs, automation

I have already executed the code for scheduler. However, I have a problem whenever I execute my scheduler. Can someone help me with this? I'll appreciate all your response.

My procedure code:

```
create or replace
procedure csv(p_query varchar2) is
 l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
 l_columnValue   varchar2(4000);
 l_status        integer;
 l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
 l_colCnt        number;
  n number := 0;

 f utl_file.file_type;
 l_line varchar2(32767);
 
 begin
 f := utl_file.fopen('TMP','mycsv.dat','W',32767);
 
 dbms_sql.parse(  l_theCursor,  p_query, dbms_sql.native );
 dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );
 
 for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
 dbms_sql.define_column(l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000);
 l_line := l_line ||  l_descTbl(i).col_name||',';
 end loop;
 utl_file.put_line(f,l_line);
 l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);
 
 while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop
 l_line := null;
 for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
 dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
 l_line := l_line || l_columnValue ||',';
 end loop;
 utl_file.put_line(f,l_line);
 end loop;
 utl_file.fclose(f);
 end;
/
```

My batch procedure code:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job (
  job_name        => 'WORKFLOW_REPORT',
  job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  job_action      => q'{csv(p_query=>'select * from reports_sample');}',
  start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=16; byminute=1; bysecond=0;',
  enabled         => TRUE);
END;
```

Comment: You need to give an example of the problem your are actually having. What errors are you seeing? What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: My problem is that I'm not sure if these procedures that I executed really runs. The version of my Oracle is 18c

Comment: Well, it *runs* if you see a new CSV file every day at 16:01 (or later).

Comment: May I know where are the exported CSV files were exported?